# Where do the Naruto movies fall in the timeline?

Tags: naruto

I know that the Naruto movies are outside the timeline in the sense that they don't affect whatever happens after them. However, they must fall somewhere in the Naruto timeline — based on who are in the movies and how the characters look like, etc. For example, if Sasuke isn't in the movie, it should take place after he left. For each of the movies, approximately what timeframe (between episodes/arcs) are they set?

The movies:

- Ninja Clash in the Land of Snow
- Legend of the Stone of Gelel
- Guardians of the Crescent Moon Kingdom
- Naruto Shippuden the Movie
- Bonds
- The Will of Fire
- The Lost Tower
- Blood Prison
- Road to Ninja
- The Last - Naruto the Movie
- Boruto: Naruto The Movie

Comment: I think Blood Prison took place after the Pain Arc as you can see Naruto is using Sage Mode.

Comment: After that The Last: Naruto the Movie came out, but we know it takes place two years after the war (they say that in the movie). Than Boruto: Naruto the Movie which is somewhere after Naruto turns into the Hokage and Boruto is taking the chunin exams.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[**Ninja Clash in the Land of Snow**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_the_Movie:_Ninja_Clash_in_the_Land_of_Snow)

> between episodes 101-106

Sakura's hair is short in the movie. She cut it during the chunin exams.

The limited opportunity team 7 has to go on a mission together between the chunin exams and Sasuke's defection would be between episodes 101-106

[**Legend of the Stone of Gelel**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_the_Movie_2:_Legend_of_the_Stone_of_Gelel)

> The movie takes place after episode 160

[**Guardians of the Crescent Moon Kingdom**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_the_Movie_3:_Guardians_of_the_Crescent_Moon_Kingdom)

> The movie takes place after episode 196, during the anime's post-Sasuke era

[**Naruto Shippuden the Movie**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto:_Shipp%C5%ABden_the_Movie)

> After Shippuden episode 53, when Naruto, Sakura, Sai and Yamato returned to the village.

[**Inheritors of the Will of Fire**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Shipp%C5%ABden_the_Movie:_The_Will_of_Fire)

> After Shippuden episode 89, due to the large influence of the Hidan and Kakuzu Arc.

[**Bonds**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Shipp%C5%ABden_the_Movie:_Bonds)

> After Shippuden episode 111, since Orochimaru was sick, which happened around when Sasuke was about to kill Orochimaru.

[**The Lost Tower**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Shipp%C5%ABden_the_Movie:_The_Lost_Tower)

> After episode 152-154, after Jiraiya's death and before Pain attacked the village.

[**Blood Prison**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_5:_Blood_Prison)

No accurate timing, due to plot inconsistencies:

> Naruto knew Sage Mode and remembered when he met his father, despite the fact that the invasion of Pain had not occurred. A, the Fourth Raikage, still had his left hand, despite having lost it during the Five Kage Summit. Naruto knew Killer B, but Naruto did not meet him until their training at the Island Turtle. Anyway, if I had to put it somewhere, I'd probably put it after episode 196.

[**Road to Ninja**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_6:_Road_to_Ninja)

> After episode 251, because Naruto must have already met his mother, and I don't think it would take place in the middle of a war. However, the fact that Konoha shinobi were fighting against Pain and the Akatsuki at the beginning would place this before the 150s and undermines the plotline of Naruto's understanding of his parents, which means that it just doesn't fit perfectly. Later in the movie, it was showed that the Akatsuki members were white Zetsu's, not the real ones (which is why they were defeated so easily and could go through the ground).

[**The Last**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last:_Naruto_the_Movie)

I'd say this movie happens after episode 493, but I would watch it after ep 500 because some stuff the happens in the end of the movie

> that hints to the episode 500.

[**Boruto: Naruto The Movie - The Day Naruto Became Hokage**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Day_Naruto_Became_Hokage)

This happens before 'Boruto: Naruto Next Generations' so watch it after Episode 500. It's a special episode, so it's about 10 minutes. The title of the short "film" says it all.

[**Boruto: Naruto The Movie**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto:_Naruto_the_Movie)

This movie happens after the 'Boruto: Naruto Next Generations' have started.

> Probably around the The Chūnin Exams.

Comment: Why are the first 3 and the fifth entry not in spoilers?

Comment: Well, the others contain potential spoilers, and they don't, so I left em

Comment: he is this uptodate?