# Are the latest Naruto movies separated from the storyline?

Tags: naruto

Will the anime have a different story than the latest movies? The movies were too rushed, and they got a bit too far from the anime story.
Edit: One of the things I want to find out is if the time-skip would also be in the Anime.

Comment: While i havnt seen the other Movies from what i have read about Naruto: The Last Movie it is canon however it's set in the time-skip before the last chapter of the Manga

Comment: They were "rushed" in relation to the Anime, but the manga ended in November of 2014. Naruto the Last was released approximately 6 months later, so they were continuations of the manga, completely unrelated to the anime's time schedule. The anime is finally ending this week as i have heard, almost 2 years after the manga, but can only do so because much of the content in the last 2 years was filler.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, even though almost all the Naruto movies are fillers, they are part of the storyline. Check this [post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/where-do-the-naruto-movies-fall-in-the-timeline).

The exceptions are the latest two movies. "The Last: Naruto Movie" is officially classified as chapter 699.5 in the Naruto manga, while "Boruto: Naruto the Movie" is in the beginning chapters of Boruto manga.