# How to review Naruto before I begin from where I left?

Tags: naruto

I was an ardent fan of Naruto and watched all of its episodes one after another and reached the end of Shippuden at that time. It was 2 years ago I guess and I last watched episode 220 or something... just after reanimation jutsu etc while the world war was going on. Then it became one episode per week and I stopped watching and thought to myself that I will pick it up again when it will be over. Alas! It is still going on but I have heard that it will end by this December. But now I am not sure that I remember the whole story and picking it up again will not be that enjoyable. So maybe I should re watch it whole and skip the filler episodes! That way I can join the current episodes within a month and watch the final as it air.

Or if I watch the Naruto movies, does it have the same story and characters and fill me in on all the important things to know before joining in on the current episodes which are going on nowadays? Movies will save me a lot of time and trouble but will they be enough?

Comment: movies don't follow the manga (i.e) the actual story, so watching them won't be of any help.

Answer (score 2):

**Spoilers in Summary below. Can't seem to get the tags to work**

I would recommend watching Naruto and Naruto:Shippuden AGAIN without the filler episodes for maximising your experience.

If you don't have the patience to re-watch, you should start from beginning of the current Saga. From your description I would say that you have watched till Season 10 of the Anime (Epsiode 197-221)

So you can pick up either from Episode 197 or from Episode 222.

> **Season 10** follows the assemblance of the Kage, the five ninja eading their respective villages, as a result of the actions from the criminal organization Akatsuki as well as the rogue ninja Sasuke Uchiha who has been siding with them.
>
> **Season 11** (Epsiodes 222-242) focuses on the ninjas' preparations to the world war against the criminal organization Akatsuki.
>
> **Season 12** (Episodes focuses on Naruto's training to control the Nine-Tailed Demon Fox and the first day of the world war against the criminal organization Akatsuki.
> [Fourth Great Ninja War. Major Events and the M&A Chapters/Episodes](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Shinobi_World_War)

The movies are MOSTLY filler. So it is upto you if you want to watch. This question should answer the order of movie watching.
[Where do the Naruto movies fall in the timeline?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/where-do-the-naruto-movies-fall-in-the-timeline)

Reddit for extended Discussion: [Naruto Movies: When to watch](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/2sipnq/when_should_i_watch_the_movies/)

If you want to rewatch without fillers, follow this guide.
[How to watch Naruto and Naruto Shipudden Filler Free](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=350747)