# What order should I start watching the Naruto series if I already started on the show

Tags: naruto

What order should I start watching the Naruto series if I already started on the show. I want to watch everything about it like the fillers and stuff too.

Comment: How do I watch a show? Start from Episode 1 and follow the order of release. Fillers still have an episode number! Movies need to be searched when they were released though.

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/where-do-the-naruto-movies-fall-in-the-timeline

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have a real point. If your watching the show already but want to see everything about it. Then the only answer is obviously to keep watching it.

Watch Naruto to completion. Then watch Naruto Shippuden. They literally run right behind each other.

The movies don't follow any real order watch them as you want.

I'd recommend skipping filler since it's so long but since you want to follow everything. Then go right ahead.

Here is a guide to all the valid Naruto timeline arcs as they exist you can grasp a few more details if there are things you don't understand there. [Naruto arc-list](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Arcs)

Also before you come in here posting questions about things that happen in the show search the `Naruto` tag that we have here and see if you questions are answered.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not starting from the beginning, personally the first arc was a pain. The Nine-tails arc is where I would start, although I haven't watched Naruto in a while.

Answer (score 1):

You have to watch everything from the beginning to understand it. You have to live it from the start to the end. If you just watch some episodes here and there, It's just entertainment.

I recommend watching the episodes including the fillers (If you can and not bored).

Use the following links:

[1. Naruto Episodes](https://www.animesays.com/list/naruto/)

[2. Naruto Shippuden Episodes](https://www.animesays.com/list/naruto-shippuden/)

Watch them in an order.