# In Naruto Shippuden Movie 5: Blood Prison, how did Naruto know Killer B?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto Shippuuden Movie 5: Blood Prison*, how did Naruto know Killer B?  When he met him, that was the time of moving island. Then the war occurred.

Comment: As explained in [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3357/) answer it is simply a plot inconsistency. The movie doesn't really fit into the timeline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do the Naruto movies fall in the timeline?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/where-do-the-naruto-movies-fall-in-the-timeline)